# Can you remove and replace keys on a Logitech K310 Keyboard?

Tags: logitech-keyboard

Two of my keys might have something in them and they're really sticky.

When I press them down, it takes a while to come back up and my '2' key gets stuck, likely from sugars or other buildup.

Can I simply pop them on/off without breaking the keyboard or they key?

Comment: You could call Logitech for a definitive answer http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/32403/related/1

Answer (score 1):

The Logitech K310 is a washable keyboard, you may be able to clean it without removing the keys.

From [Logitech's Support Article](https://support.logitech.com/support/en_us/article/32402?product=a0qi00000069vEpAAI):

> Your keyboard is hand-washable. Follow the steps below to clean the
>   keyboard without damaging it:
>
> - Unplug the keyboard.
> - Cover the end of the USB cable with the attached cap.
> - Use dish washing liquid and the keyboard brush to wash the keyboard.
> - Water temperature should be less than 50° C (120° F) and the water should not be deeper than 30 cm (11 inches).
> - Don't submerge the cable.
> - Don't use a dishwasher.
> - Don't use abrasives, alcohol, solvents, or detergents.
> - Rinse thoroughly to remove all of the dish washing liquid.
> - Dry at room temperature.
> - Wipe with clean towel.
> - Air dry overnight (8 hours).
> - Don't use a hot-air drier.
> - Reconnect the keyboard.
>
> **WARNING:** Do not plug a wet cable into your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed a key from my k360 keyboard with a screw driver and put it back in, works fine. I guess it's the same technology for the k310.

Comment: Do you NEED a screwdriver?

Comment: By the way, the keys are different on this keyboard. They're raised and this is also a washable keyboard..

Comment: Of course you don't need a screw driver, I just had it at my desk. You are right though, after double-checking with pictures, your keyboard has a different technology than mine. There is one way to find out if you can remove them...get a screw driver and test on the caps lock key. In the worst case you get rid of that one, nobody uses it anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I'm worried about that. Since using a gentle pull on one of the keys doesn't budge it.. afraid I might break it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove a key (the little white square bit that goes up and down in the hole), but it was difficult. There were tabs on all four sides that had to be pushed inwards at the same time, which is nearly impossible unless you've got four hands.

After prising off the key top, I used two small flat bladed screwdrivers to push in two tabs at once on adjacent sides, and pointy nosed pliers to pull up one corner so they didn't pop back down again while I did the other two.

I found that the sides of this square piece were coated in red sticky stuff, soft drink or something. I cleaned it off, and also the edges of the hole, and it was fine when I put it all back.

For the second sticky key I fixed, I didn't bother pulling the white bit out. I just pulled off the key top then wiped around the exposed part of the white square with a cotton bud dipped in soapy water. Then I pressed it down a few times and repeated till it was moving without sticking.

Washing the keyboard probably would have fixed it too, by dissolving the stuff out, but I've heard of keyboards not working after that, even though they're supposed to be waterproof.